# smooth topos as generalized smooth space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, topos-theory, generalized-smooth-spaces

I'm interested in generalized smooth spaces. I know there are several spaces such as Deffeological space, Frölicher space, Chen space, etc... and there are some papers compare them. However, I haven't found one which compares smooth topos to them. (I don't have literacy to do it on my own yet.)

What are characteristics of smooth topos as generalized smooth space compared to other kinds of them?

Comment: The [nLab entry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+topos) explains it well enough imo. In a nutshell - smooth topos axiomatizes the whole category of smooth spaces rather than one single smooth space. That said, one might assign to a single smooth space $X$ a modification of the smooth topos which determines $X$. Objects of this modification may be viewed as families of smooth spaces varying over $X$. It is similar to what in algebraic geometry is called gros topos: to a scheme $X$ one assigns the topos of sheaves on $\text{Schemes}/X$.

Comment: Also note that if the smooth topos is defined as sheaves over the category of manifold/opens of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the étale topology then the object of the smooth topos are closely related to Diffeological spaces (which are essentially the effective sheaves over the same site)